# Spring and Jquery

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I use Spring Framework 3.1 and I have page, which displays a list of objects.
For example:

```
<c:forEach var="person" items="${restaurants}">
...
</c:forEach>
```

And the code of controller method (1):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/people",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 private String restaurants(Map<String, Object> map) {
    List<Restaurant> r=new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        Restaurant restaurant=new Restaurant();
        restaurant.setAbout("bla bla!"+i);
        restaurant.setName("REstaurant"+i);
        r.add(restaurant);
    }
    map.put("restaurants",r);
    return "/restaurants";
  }
```

Now I want to change the information dynamically, using AJAX.

My method for AJAX POST request (2):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/restaurant")
private  @ResponseBody List<Restaurant> restaurant(Map<String, Object> map,
@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Long id,HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Restaurant> r=new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        Restaurant restaurant=new Restaurant();
        restaurant.setAbout("bla bla bla!"+i);
        restaurant.setName("REstaurant"+i);
        r.add(restaurant);
    }
    return r;
}
```

How can I display the received information after ajax request? Can I do that again with  c:forEach tag? I know that I should rewrite my second method.
Depending on id paramter in second method, get objects and put it to the same Model Page which used in first method?

Comment: Nothing in google that helped you? for example http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-mvc-ajax-and-json-part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this, but you cannot mix the `c:forEach` tag with an Ajax request that returns `JSON`.

The first approach is to send an `Ajax` request that retrieves the `JSON` data from the second controller.

```
$.post("/restaurant", {id:1}, function(data){
   /* Write the json returned in the data parameter
      to the user interface by creating dynamic HTML
    */  
});
```

This approach cannot leverage the `for:each` tag since the ajax request is handled by the client and the JSTL `foreach` tag is a server side technique.

The other approach is to put the markup for the select tag into a fragment.  This would allow you to reuse the component as well as call it independently.

So lets say in your main page (restraunts) you have:

```
<div id="theSelect">
   <jsp:include page="myFragment.jsp"/>
</div>
```

And the fragment (myFragment.jsp) looks like:

```
<c:forEach var="person" items="${restaurants}">
...
</c:forEach>
```

You could modify the controller to return the view instead of the JSON, assuming that an appropriate ViewResolver is setup.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/restaurant")
private  String restaurant(Map<String, Object> map,
@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Long id,HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Restaurant> r=new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        Restaurant restaurant=new Restaurant();
        restaurant.setAbout("bla bla bla!"+i);
        restaurant.setName("REstaurant"+i);
        r.add(restaurant);
    }
    map.put("restaurants",r);
    return "myFragment";
}
```

You could then reload the `select` element using jQuery:

```
$("#theSelect").load("/restraunt");
```

So in a nutshell I recommend two approaches:

1. Retrieve the JSON via ajax and build the select element via Javascript, then replace the existing select element with the newly built element.  This is a traditional client side approach.
2. Make the select element a fragment.  Make the response of your controller return the fragment and load this element into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin's post is along the right lines, you do need to have a few jars added to your configuration and you need to implement a ContentNegotiatingViewResolver for it to produce JSON from your controller.

[This video](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/springmvc-intro) covers all of the steps to setup exactly what you are trying to do.